# Content Editable inside a carousel causing the event propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a editable div dynamically with the following line.

```
<div class='reflection-field' contenteditable="true" data-number="${index}"></div>
```

Expected: When I click on the rendered div, i expect it to show the cursor at the start.

Issue: This div is inside of a "Slide" div of a Carousel. So, when I click on this content editable div, it propagates the event and activates the event to the parent carousel which activates the "grab slide" event. This leads to a "Move" mouse pointer and NO cursor inside the editable.

I am using jQuery & owl Carousel 2 in this project.

```
$(".reflection-field").click(function( event ) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

and  this

```
$(".owl-carousel").on("click",".reflection-field", function( event ) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   propStopped( event )
});

function propStopped( event ) {
 if ( event.isPropagationStopped() ) {
   console.log("called");
 } else {
console.log("not called");
 }
}
//called
```

But, its not happening. Will really appreciate the help.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pr2wn6ug/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the deal.

The "mousedown" evokes the grab in the Owl-Carousel-2.

So this made it work

```
$(".reflection-field").on("click tap mousedown", function( event ) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can intentionally enable or disable draggable feature at run-time. Below code will work for Owl-Carousel and other similar problem:

```
$(".reflection-field").draggable()
      .click(function() {
        $(this).draggable({ disabled: false });
    }).dblclick(function() {
        $(this).draggable({ disabled: true });
    });
```

Don't forget to add jQuery-ui library to make it work.
        ​